# MathQuill and set operators

Tags: latex, mathquill

When using MathQuill one needs to type `\nsub` to get the `⊈` symbol. The latex you get back is `\not\subset`, which is fine.

But when you try to set back the same `\not\subset` expression to the MathQuill field, you get a different result : `\neg\subset`, which translates to a different rendering.

The problem can be reproduced directly on the MathQuill page (http://mathquill.com/) using the browser console :

[image]

Any ideas on how to handle or work around this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MathQuill will accept `\nsub` while typing, but also `\notsubset`, which got me to a simple find-and-replace solution, which does not require any other code change.

Not the best, but it works; the only downside is that the list of text replacements is fixed; the set operators are the one I found; could be more.

```js
// special math pre-processing
var mathFix = {
    "\\not\\subset" : "\\notsubset",
    "\\not\\supset" : "\\notsupset"
}
                        
var mathTextFixed = '<your latex here>';
Object.keys(mathFix).forEach(function(t1) {
    mathTextFixed = mathTextFixed.replace(t1, mathFix[t1]);
});

mathField.latex(mathTextFixed);
```